# Can I call dma_unmap_single after dma_sync_single_for_cpu?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver, dma

I have a situation where I need to call `dma_unmap_single` after `dma_sync_single_for_cpu`. Below is my scenario.

1. Allocate memory for a buffer using `kmalloc()`
2. Map the buffer to device using `dma_map_single` with `DMA_FROM_DEVICE` direction.
3. After receiving packet, get buffer ownership using `dma_sync_single_for_cpu`.
4. After some time, if some other function in kernel using same buffer, unmap buffer from device using `dma_unmap_single` with `DMA_FROM_DEVICE` direction.

Are all the above steps acceptable?

Comment: DMA map API is about address space, it might also have a side effect as bounce buffers when IOMMU is in use. The steps you described are okay as long as you have everything serialized in terms of access to that buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer "ownership" (CPU or device) matters only for deciding who is allowed to access the buffer's contents.

`dma_unmap_single()` does not care about the contents; it can be called in either state.

Please note that after the DMA unmapping, the memory again "belongs" to the CPU. If you are doing only a single DMA transfer, you do not need to call `dma_sync_single_for_cpu()`; you can just read the buffer after the `dma_unmap_single()` call.